# Why is my map not showing up on my contact page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I tried following the google steps to add the map to my page,
Got the key, did everything as explained, but it is not showing up.

```
 `

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;background:grey;">
</div>

 <script>
          function myMap(){
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.2), zoom:10
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
              }
 </script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE"></script>

 `
```

Comment: do you call `myMap() ` anywhere?

Comment: Replace `js?key=MY_KEY_HERE` with `js?callback=myMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mazz, I was able to solve this;
turns out I was calling a diferent function. `map()` instead of `myMap()`.
It's now working fine.
Thank you.

`<body onload="myMap()">`